# str_detect with multiple strings (and not or) of the same kind using R

Tags: r, regex, string, grepl

I want to use str_detect or similar to identify values where the same string occurs at least twice, separately.

For example, if I want to identify values with the word "detect" in it, twice, from find.variable:

```
find.variable <- c("detect me a string detect", "detect string", "string", "detect detect", "detectdetect")
```

The output I want is:

```
logi [1:5] TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

It does not matter if the value is repeated within the string, e.g. detectdetect, though it may be good to have an alternative solution which excludes results where the string is not "detect", for example with a desired output:

```
logi [1:5] TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

This may be a variation of:

```
find.variable.string <- str_detect(find.variable, "detect")
```

But I am also happy to hear other suggestions - I suspect regex may be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use -

```
library(stringr)

str_detect(find.variable, '\\bdetect\\b.*\\bdetect\\b')
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

If you want to allow consecutive values of `'detect'`, use

```
str_detect(find.variable, 'detect.*detect')
```

---

You can also use `str_count` to count number of detects in a string.

```
str_count(find.variable, 'detect') == 2
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Note that the last value is `TRUE` in case of `str_count`.